# jQuery :: in jQuery Tools Scrollable - changing mouse scroll speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

How can I change the speed of scrolling using the mouse in jQuery Tools Scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.  The actually mouse sensitivity is outside of the control of jquery.

You could somewhat simulate this by creating your own custom slider that when moved scrolls content at double the speed or something like that.  However, the actually speed that the mouse pointer moves will be unchanged.

Comment: How do I simulate it? Suppose if I capture sliding by mouse scroll then I can ensure it only slides half of the times or something of that sort, to reduce the mouse scroll. Do you have any ideas on how to implement that kind of behaviour?

Comment: probably something with jquery slider http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider but it's probably more trouble than it's worth.